# How to detect MySql server failure?

Tags: mysql, database, database-replication

If for any reason MySql server goes down,

1. What are the ways I could still show my page to user? Probably having a backup DB server would help?
2. If I've multiple DB servers and one goes down, I can fetch data from another temporary server? How to detect that main server is down? Who would select alternate server? role of reverse proxy server here? Is [Varnish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish_%28software%29) capable of doing this kind of switching via VCL (Varnish Configuration Language)?
3. Approach to maintain copy of main DB on temporary server? Master slave replica method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your service depends on database heavily, yes you need to have a backup DB. Otherwise, if it's only supporting some minor functionality, you could apply the principle of "degradable experience" in that case.
2. Why not write a small service/daemon that acts as an interface to your DB,  runs on your server machine and polls your servers for activity? This service would then handle all of the DB-related queries independently, select the appropriate server, etc so your www service would only forward requests to the daemon and receive results  accordingly.